# Solr 8.9.0 don't import datas from SSMS database using DIH

Tags: java, sql, solr

I'm new to Solr, and I'm trying to import some datas from a local database on SQL Server Management Studio. I use a schemaless core (created with the command create -c nameofcore) but when I hit the execute button of the DIH the import ends pretty much instantly,
showing this :
Requests: 1 , Fetched: 0 , Skipped: 0 , Processed: 0 (on green like it was a succes)

So nothing is imported, it seems there is no problem for the request (here is no logs by the way), but it don't import anything.
The strangest thing is that my internship superisor succeded at doigng that on his computer and could not help me this, even when I copied his config (changing the connexion to the database).
About that, here is my dataconfig, as I think it my come from here. The user is Sysadmin and dbowner of the database.

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\SQLEXPRESS:1433;databaseName=Db_Asset"
user="myuser"
password="mypassword" />
<document>
    <entity name="asset"
        query="SELECT Id, Name FROM FunctionalAssets"
        deltaQuery="SELECT Id FROM FunctionalAssets WHERE ModifiedOn > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'"
    >
        <field column="Name" name="name" />
    </entity>
</document>
```

I don't know if I should pu the solrconfig and managed schema, as they are really big files, but I  imported the default DIH and mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.jre8.jar for the communication between java and the base.
If it could matter, my session is not an administrator on my computer.
So if anybody could help me  to succeed at the import it would be great

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

My compagny finally gave me an admin account and by lanching solr from an admin cmd the importation worked.
Case closed